# Wrong count of call method cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a code

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.objectIdArray.count;
}
```

this method returned 7.I check it in debug mode.But delegate method such as

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// !!!!!!!!!!!!!
        NSLog(@"%d\n",self.objectIdArray.count);
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"OrderListCell"];
        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"OrderListCell" owner:nil options:nil];
            cell = [topLevelObjects lastObject];
            [((OrderListCell *) cell).activityIndicatorView startAnimating];

        }

        ((OrderListCell *) cell).delegate = self;
        [((OrderListCell *) cell) prepareOrderListCell:[self.objectIdArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

        return cell;

    }
```

In logs 7 was writed 6 (!) times.Any solutions?

Comment: are you forgetting array indexes start at 0 rather than 1?

Comment: oh,no.In logs "OK" was writed 6 times.But should be 7,as self.objectIdArray.count = 7

Comment: It's probably displaying 7 in the first on because it starts at 0, meaning there will be 7 values for 6 objects

Comment: I'm quite confident that cellForRowAtIndexPath is invoked for every cell that is displayed, plus a few on the "edges" if you don't scroll all the way through.  (And you can get multiple calls per cell if you scroll back and forth.)  You're missing something, perhaps a NSLog that's buried in other output.

Comment: (What symptom led you to count the calls in the first place?)

Comment: (And it's always a good idea to add more to an NSLog than simply a number.  Eg, `NSLog(@"array count = %d", self.objectIdArray.count);`.  Makes it a lot easier to search for/find individual logs in the console.)

Comment: it's absolutely true.NSLog must be helpful.
I delete project from simulator and it helps for me.Now method is called 7 times.But i dont know how this resolved my problem

Comment: We still don't know what your problem was (though operator malfunction appears likely).

Answer (score 3):

cellForRowAtIndexPath is only called when the cell is displayed. Are you sure that 7 cells would fit in your screen?

Comment: @incmiko -- Only for displayed cells, or cells that are about to be displayed.

Comment: yes thats right  cells that are about to be displayed, so not only for displayed cells

Answer (score 0):

try checking the array length and then verify against call for delegate methods.

Answer (score 0):

How many cells are visible on your screen? `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method only call for the visible and  cells that are about to be displayed. If you scrolldown in your tableview it will be get called for the lastone too !

Comment: after scroll this method not called